# Why does my awk redirection not work?

Tags: bash, awk, io-redirection

Im trying to redirect my output to replace the contents of my file but if I do this it doesn't change my output at all

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh_config_path="$HOME/.ssh/config"
temp_ssh_config_path="$HOME/.ssh/config_temporary"

new_primary_username=$1
curr_primary_username=`awk '/^Host github\.com$/,/#Username/{print $2}' $ssh_config_path | tail -1`
new_user_name=`awk "/^Host github-$new_primary_username$/,/#Name/{print $2}" $ssh_config_path | tail -1 | sed 's/#Name //' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'`
new_user_email=`awk "/^Host github-$new_primary_username$/,/#Email/{print $2}" $ssh_config_path | tail -1 | sed 's/#Email //' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'`

echo "Switching from $curr_primary_username to $new_primary_username"
echo "Setting name to $new_user_name"
echo "Setting email to $new_user_email"

awk "
 !x{x=sub(/github-$new_primary_username/,\"github.com\")}
 !y{y=sub(/github\.com/,\"github-$curr_primary_username\")}
 1" $ssh_config_path > temp_ssh_config_path && mv temp_ssh_config_path ssh_config_path
```

but if I do this I get the correct output on my terminal screen

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh_config_path="$HOME/.ssh/config"
temp_ssh_config_path="$HOME/.ssh/config_temporary"

new_primary_username=$1
curr_primary_username=`awk '/^Host github\.com$/,/#Username/{print $2}' $ssh_config_path | tail -1`
new_user_name=`awk "/^Host github-$new_primary_username$/,/#Name/{print $2}" $ssh_config_path | tail -1 | sed 's/#Name //' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'`
new_user_email=`awk "/^Host github-$new_primary_username$/,/#Email/{print $2}" $ssh_config_path | tail -1 | sed 's/#Email //' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'`

echo "Switching from $curr_primary_username to $new_primary_username"
echo "Setting name to $new_user_name"
echo "Setting email to $new_user_email"

awk "
 !x{x=sub(/github-$new_primary_username/,\"github.com\")}
 !y{y=sub(/github\.com/,\"github-$curr_primary_username\")}
 1" $ssh_config_path
```

Comment: Create a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. I'm sure you can reduce what we need to look at a lot and so help us to help you. Never enclose any script for awk or any other command in double quotes (`awk "script"`), always single (`awk 'script'`) as we've shown you in  the answers to your previous questions. Use `$(cmd)`, not the obsolete `\`cmd\`` syntax. Always double quote every shell variable (e.g. `"$ssh_config_path"`, not `$ssh_config_path`) unless you have a specific purpose in mind and fully understand all the implications and caveats of not doing so. Fix all of that first.

Comment: It looks ok to me. Is there an error? Is it creating an empty file and displaying to the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's disappointing how far you've veered from the answers you were given but in any case here's the correct syntax for your script (untested since you didn't provide any sample input/output):

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh_config_path="$HOME/.ssh/config"
temp_ssh_config_path="$HOME/.ssh/config_temporary"

new_primary_username="$1"
curr_primary_username=$(awk 'f&&/#Username/{print $2; exit} /^Host github\.com$/{f=1}' "$ssh_config_path")
new_user_name=$(awk -v npu="$new_primary_username" 'f&&/#Name/{print $2; exit} $0~"^Host github-"npu"$"{f=1}' "$ssh_config_path")
new_user_email=$(awk -v npu="$new_primary_username" 'f&&/#Email/{print $2; exit} $0~"^Host github-"npu"$"{f=1}' "$ssh_config_path")

echo "Switching from $curr_primary_username to $new_primary_username"
echo "Setting name to $new_user_name"
echo "Setting email to $new_user_email"

awk -v npu="$new_primary_username" -v cpu="$curr_primary_username" '
 !x{x=sub("github-"npu,"github.com")}
 !y{y=sub(/github\.com/,"github-"cpu)}
1' "$ssh_config_path" > temp_ssh_config_path && mv temp_ssh_config_path "$ssh_config_path"
```

By doing that I noticed that your last statement was:

```
mv temp_ssh_config_path ssh_config_path
```

when you probably meant:

```
mv temp_ssh_config_path "$ssh_config_path"
```

and that would have caused a problem with your expected output file being empty.

The whole thing should, of course, have been written as just 1 simple awk script.